# NSRangeException - index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableViewController with static cells in it. What I am trying to do is add a tableView with dynamic cells inside one of those static cells.

self.notTakenDates is an array, and so is self.takenDates

So I have this code:

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    var numberOfSections: Int?
    var table: String = ""  //Just so I know for what table I run the code
    if tableView == self.progressTableView {
        table = "progressTableView"
        numberOfSections = 2
    }
    if tableView == self.tableView {
        table = "self.tableView"
        numberOfSections = 1
    }
    print("Number of sections: \(numberOfSections) for \(table)")
    return numberOfSections ?? 0
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    var numberOfRows: Int = 0
    if tableView == self.progressTableView {
        if section == 0 { numberOfRows = self.notTakenDates.count }
        if section == 1 { numberOfRows = self.takenDates.count }
        print("progressTableview - Number of rows: \(numberOfRows) in section \(section)")
    }
    if tableView == self.tableView {
        numberOfRows = 8
        print("self.tableview - Number of rows: \(numberOfRows) in section \(section)")
    }

    return numberOfRows
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = UITableViewCell()
    var table: String = ""
    if tableView == self.tableView {
        table = "self.tableView"
        //Switch statement is for now - I think there must be a way to get those static cells using some shortcut?
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            cell = self.nameCell
        case 1:
            cell = self.dosageCell
        case 2:
            cell = self.noteCell
        case 3:
            cell = self.periodCell
        case 4:
            cell = self.remindersCell
        case 5:
            cell = self.progressCell
        case 6:
            cell = self.blankCell
        case 7:
            cell = self.buttonCell
        default:
            cell = UITableViewCell()
        }
    } else if tableView == self.progressTableView {
        table = "self.progressTableView"
        let progressCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ProgressCell") as! ProgressTableViewCell
        progressCell.dateLabel.text = "Hello" //Just for now - will be changed after I figure out how to fix this error
        cell = progressCell
    }
    return cell
}
```

What I see in my output is:

```
Number of sections: Optional(1) for self.tableView
self.tableview - Number of rows: 8 in section 0
Number of sections: Optional(2) for progressTableView
2016-03-28 14:08:28.257 MyApp[1166:75146] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
```

What did I do wrong? It must be something in numberOfRowsInSection, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Which line does it crash on?  (If you don't know, you can set breakpoints and step through code to find out.)

Comment: I don't really know how to do it properly. I have never used breakpoints before as there was no need for them.

Comment: It's in the Xcode documentation.

Comment: The app terminates as soon as numberOfSectionsInTableView is run for the  progressTableView in one of those cells. When it crashes it brings me to the  "class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {..."